# Why do I have an error message when inverting an image in openCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am processing a UIImage for contour creation and in that process I am firstly inverting it, then making it gray. Here is the code:

```
+(UIImage *)processInvertedImage:(UIImage *)image {

cv::Mat mat;
UIImageToMat(image, mat);

cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY); 

cv::Mat inverted;
cv::invert(gray, inverted);   //// here it crashes

UIImage *binImg = MatToUIImage(inverted);   

return binImg;
```

}

This is the error code:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.2) /Volumes/build-storage/build/3_4_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp:839: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == 5 || type == 6 in function 'invert'

(lldb)

Why can't I use the invert methode? I tried to invert before converting to gray, but that did not make a difference.

Comment: "inverted = !gray;" please read the doc next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the document](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gad278044679d4ecf20f7622cc151aaaa2) : `cv::invert()` requires `CV_32F` or `CV_64F` as type, not `CV_8U` in your case. Also, just want to make sure you want the right inverse, `cv::inverse()` is the mathematical inverse, not image processing inverse.

Comment: instead of white - black I want the picture to convert to black-white, so, I guess invert() is correct, right? I did try to do the invert() before processing to gray. isn't a UIImage CV_32F (I am taking this directly from the camera).

Comment: No, they are typically 'CV_8U'. And this method is not what you want. You are either looking for 'inverted=255-gray' or 'inverted=255^gray'.