# Why is my app crashing when I try to invert a UIImage in openCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have been playing around with this now for a long time and I can't get the following code going for some reason.

```
+(UIImage *)processInvertedImage:(UIImage *)image {

    cv::Mat mat;
    UIImageToMat(image, mat);   ///this is CV_8U from iPhone camera

    cv::Mat output;
    mat.convertTo(output, CV_32F);   ///cv::invert() requires CV_32F!! (apparently)

    cv::Mat invert;
    cv::invert(output, invert);     /// app crashes here, error message below

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(invert, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);  

    UIImage *binImg = MatToUIImage(gray);

    return binImg;

}
```

I am getting the following error code:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.2) /Volumes/build-storage/build/3_4_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp:839: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == 5 || type == 6 in function 'invert'

what does this type == 5 || type == 6 mean?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203280/why-do-i-have-an-error-message-when-inverting-an-image-in-opencv/53203558#53203558). You have exactly his problem. See my answer and comment for details.

Comment: Hi Quang, yes, that was my question yesterday. Just needed to ask it again since after I introduced your suggestions it actually still does not work.

Comment: you suggested the conversion to CV_32F, but still crashing with exactly the same error message, so there must be something else going on here.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to convert to gray scale and then do the invert function?? with invert requiring CV_23F is that then possible at all?

Comment: I didn't notice the same poster. I am adding an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer this one for good. `type == 5 || type == 6` means you need to work with `CV_32F` or `CV_64F`. However, `UIImage` usually has 4 channels. I bet your `UIImageToMat` yields a mat of type `CV_8UC3` . So `mat` has type `CV_8UC3`, and `output` will most likely has type `CV_32FC3`, not just `CV_32F`. And again, when you use `cv::invert()`, you are looking at **mathematical inverse**, that is `output * mat = identity_matrix`.

```
+(UIImage *)processInvertedImage:(UIImage *)image {

    cv::Mat mat;
    UIImageToMat(image, mat);   ///this is CV_8U from iPhone camera

    if (mat.type() == CV_8UC3) {
        NSLog(@"mat type is CV_8UC3"); // mostlikely this
    } else if (mat.type() == CV_8UC4){
        NSLog(@"mat type is CV_8UC4");
    }

    cv::Mat output;
    mat.convertTo(output, CV_32F);   ///cv::invert() requires CV_32F!! (apparently)
    if (output.type() == CV_32FC3){
        NSLog(@"output type is CV_32FC3"); // most likely this 
    }

    // this is really bad naming, since you seem to use namespace cv somewhere, 
    // as CV_32F doesn't have cv:: prefix
    cv::Mat invert;                
    cv::invert(output, invert);     /// app crashes here, error message below

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(invert, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);  

    UIImage *binImg = MatToUIImage(gray);

    return binImg;

}
```

Edit: If you need *image processing* inverse, then you can do something similar to what you had in last question:

```
+(UIImage *)processInvertedImage:(UIImage *)image {
    cv::Mat mat;
    UIImageToMat(image, mat);

    // convert to RGB
    cv::Mat rgb
    cv::cvtColor(mat, rgb, COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    // create mat of same size and type with values 255
    cv::Mat dummy(rgb.size(), rgb.type(), cv::Scalar(255,255,255));

    // three channels
    cv::Mat rgb_invert = dummy ^ rgb;

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(rgb, gray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    cv::Mat gray_invert = 255 ^ gray;

    // depending what invert you would like
    UIImage* binImg = MatToUIImage(rgb_invert);

    return binImg;
}
```

Comment: ok, ran it.  is is is CV_8UC4. crashed before it came to the CV_32F question

Comment: I believed you when you said it crashed at the `invert` function :D. You can go around by `cv::cvtColor(mat, gray, COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)` and `gray.convertTo(output, CV_32F)`. But then, `invert` will be `CV_32F`, not `RGB`, i.e. `CV_8UC3`. Anyway, I am still not sure why you need **mathematical inverse** of an image.

Comment: I actually don't need mathematical inverse . I misunderstood this. all I want is to change the dark background to light background, which I need for shape recognition. which function do you suggest

Comment: ran it as per above suggestion and error message has changed now to :  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.2) /Volumes/build-storage/build/3_4_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp:863: error: (-215:Assertion failed) m == n in function 'invert'

Comment: That's because only square matrices have **mathematical inverses**. See edit for image processing inverse.

Comment: perfect, it's working!!! Great Thanks!!  When I connect it to the video live stream it crashes, I guess because this is too CPU intense.